# CSS - Align list item before

Tags: css

I added a before my list item so I can use a custom image as the bullet point like so:

```
li.list-item-2::before {
    content: '' !important;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-image: url(/IMG_6331.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This does use my custom image, but for some reason on the second line of the list item does not align properly (see image) the second line of text goes below the image, when I want that second line to line up with the text on the first line. How do I fix that?

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="service-list">
<li class="list-item-1" style="font-weight: 400;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Surfaces are thoroughly pressure washed, using adjustable pressure, and the appropriate accessories, in order to protect your surface.</span></li>
<li class="list-item-2"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Depending on your surface, a spray and/or roll technique is used to ensure uniform coverage</span><span style="font-weight: 400;"> through our 2 coat non-slip application.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please show the HTML structure

Comment: @vsync added HTML

Comment: please better explain in the title next time what kind of alignment you want because your vertical alignment also is far from perfect, regardless of text horizontal alignment